# Can I close mail-smtp port on Wildfly?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I want to close mail-smtp port.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets"
 default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <!--<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">-->
        <!--<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>-->
    <!--</outbound-socket-binding>-->
</socket-binding-group>
```

Can I disable mail subsystem if I will not use mail?

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
        <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you should remove mail service, subsystem can be removed

Remove extension: `<extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>`

Remove the complete subsystem mail:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
    <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
        <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
    </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

Remove outbound-socket-binding mail-smtp

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
    <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

You can also use CLI to remove the subsystem:

```
/subsystem=mail:remove
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=mail-smtp:remove
/extension=org.jboss.as.mail:remove
:reload
```